# how to implement a less than query when using rust diesel

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am using rust diesel to query the PostgreSQL 13 database,now I want to do a query like this:

```
select *
from fav
where playlist_id = 1
and play_count < 100
```

what I am doing using diesel rust code like this:

```
let playlist_records = favorites.filter(source_id.eq(req_song_id))
        .filter(play_count<100)
        .limit(1)
        .load::<QueryFavorites>(&connection)
        .expect("Error loading favorite");
```

seems did not work as expect, I read the diesel document but did not found the less than query demo, what should I do to implement an less than query using rust diesel?

Comment: Query filters are covered by the traits in the [`expression_methods`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.7/diesel/expression_methods/index.html) module. You should find everything documented there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use diesel's methods for comparison within the filter call.

I just quickly googled "rust diesel filter" to check the official documentation, and there I found the `le` method: https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/expression_methods/trait.ExpressionMethods.html#method.lt

Their example:

```rust
let data = users
    .select(name)
    .filter(id.lt(2))
    .first::<String>(&connection)?;
```

This filters for everything where `id < 2`.

So in your case, just write `.filter(play_count.lt(100))` I think.